# Posting JSON with JQuery

Tags: json, jquery

Trying to get JQuery to post JSON to a server:

```
$.ajax({  
  url: "/path/to/url",  
  type: "POST",  
  dataType: "json",  
  contentType: "json",  
  data: {"foo": "bar"},  
  success: function(){              
    alert("success :-)");  
  },  
  error: function(){  
    alert("fail :-(");  
  }  
});
```

Problem is the data appears on the server as `"foo=bar"` rather than the desired `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}`.

I thought specifying either the dataType or contentType params would do the trick, but no.

Anyone know the correct ajax configuration ? [or alternatively a way of serialising the 'data' parameter as JSON prior to posting ?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js):

```
data: JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Datatype is for returned data.  Contenttype is not applicable, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

It can only send strings, I use `JSON.stringify` on my created javascript objects, in your case you could just manually code the string.

You will also need to access the string on server side, for that if you are using java I can recommened google's [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)