# How can i change options in dropdowns if it is generated dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript

I do have this script to generate three dropdowns and one text input field for my webform that i have to submit to a database using PHP. This form is HTML but only this part is javascript to populate the fields. I am using this javascript to generate approx 15 sets of these dropdowns and text input fields. (1 set = 3 dropdowns and 1 input text field).

My question is : If user selects an option from first dropdown then the options in the other two dropdowns should change according to the selected option in the first drodown.

What I wanted to is after generating the desired number of sets by selecting the number from the dropdown in this fiddle, it will generate sets od 3 dropdowns and 1 input field dynamically.

So if someone selects option one from the first dropdown it should change the options in the other dropdowns as well.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/harshdhama/E3gWX/)

**THE SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('sel').value; i++) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var j = 1;
            var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#dropbox");
            $("<select>").attr("name", "input1_"+j).appendTo(newDiv).append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));
            $("<select>").attr("name", "input2_"+j).appendTo(newDiv).append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));
            $("<select>").attr("name", "input3_"+j).appendTo(newDiv).append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));
            $("<input>").attr("name", "input4_"+j).appendTo(newDiv);
            $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            })
                j++;
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**THE HTML:**

```
<form>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="01" >01</option>
                        <option value="02" >02</option>
                        <option value="03" >03</option>
                        <option value="04" >04</option>
                        <option value="05" >05</option>
                        <option value="06" >06</option>
                        <option value="07" >07</option>
                        <option value="08" >08</option>
                        <option value="09" >09</option>
                        <option value="10" >10</option>
                        <option value="11" >11</option>
                        <option value="12" >12</option>
                        <option value="13" >13</option>
                        <option value="14" >14</option>
                        <option value="15" >15</option>
                        </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add" />

    <div id="dropbox"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you want to know how to react on a user selection in the dropdown? do you want to modify and/or select an option of an existing dropdown? Is your probelm related to the PHP back-end? What did you try?

Comment: yes i want to change the options of the dropdown based on the selection made in the previous dropdowns. What i tried was to find a working example but i was unable to use it for me as my dropdowns are generated dynamically using a script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery, I suggest to add a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to your dropdown. (The linked jQuery docs page contains a full example).

Regarding filling the other 2 drop-downs, you have several options, such as:

1. Static: Your PHP code that creates the page fills in a javascript array with all possible options needed according to user choice in the 1st dropdown. Then your javascript code can use this array whenever a change event is triggered.
2. Dynamic: If sub-choices can't be predicted or loaded at page load, use a jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to query the server for options matching user choice. You may also want to read about the [JSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854629) data format (supported by PHP using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution, but i am new to javascript and really don't know how to use your answer successfully for me.

Comment: appreciated but still as i stated earlier that i am very new to this, it's going to be Rocket Science for me to understand and use it for myself.

Comment: No sorry, I can put you on the right track but I can't neither do the work for you or write a complete tutorial for the problem at hand. You'll have to do more research on you own.

Comment: i understand that. So what shall i do?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/REcnr/)

I gave the sel and the button an ID and changed the dom access to jQuery

I also use the "i" and "j" now

Assuming you wanted to syncronise the 3 selects, the code could look like this

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i=0,n=$('#sel').val();i<n; i++) {
      var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#dropbox");
      for (var j=0;j<3;j++) {
        var id = "input"+i+"_"+j;
        $("<select>")
          .attr("id",id)
          .attr("name",id)
          .on("change",function() {
            // set all other select's value to this value
            $(this).siblings("select").val(this.value);
          })
          .append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), 
            $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"))
          .appendTo(newDiv);
      } // j
      $("<input>")
          .attr("name", "input"+i+"_"+j)
          .appendTo(newDiv);
      $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
      })
    } // i
  })
})​
```

Comment: thank you for providing a solution. but, the problem is that i am very new to javascript so i really do not know how to use your provided solution to my use. Can you please help ahead of this.

Comment: alright let me try. This is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/harshdhama/E3gWX/) what i wanted to is after generating the desired number of sets by selecting the number from the dropdown in this fiddle, it will generate sets od 3 dropdowns and 1 input field dynamically. So if someone selects option one from the   first dropdown it should change the options in the other dropdowns as well. Let me know if you want me to be more specific

Comment: Sir, was i able to made myself clear with the help of this JSFIDDLE (if you already had a look at that)?