# How can i change options in drop down menus if they are generated dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i change options in dropdowns if it is generated dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872713/how-can-i-change-options-in-dropdowns-if-it-is-generated-dynamically)

I am using this JSFIDDLE that can generate some drop down menus and text input fields. To be specific about what it do : It generates sets of some input fields dynamically where 1 set= 3 drop downs and 1 text input field. I am using it to generate upto 15 of these on my web form that is going to be submitted to a database using PHP.

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/harshdhama/E3gWX/)

What i need to do is this:
Let us say that in this jsfiddle linked above some one selects 5 and click ADD button, so it will generate 5 sets of inputs dynamically where 1 set = 3 dropdowns + 1 text input field and 1 remove button to remove that particular set. Now let's take set 1. If user selects something in first dropdown of this set it should change the options available in rest of the two drop downs in this same set. (I mean to say it should change the option sin the rest of drop down menus according to the subject selected in the first drop down.)

For an example to what i want to do with my working jsfiddle, you can refer to this one [Chain dropdowns](http://jsfiddle.net/7K2Eu/63/)

I have never used javascript and this is the only javascript part that i am having in my web form and facing trouble with. NEED HELP

Comment: you should to clarify what you want..

Comment: what is need : Let us say that in this jsfiddle linked above some one selects 5 and click ADD button, so it will generate 5 sets of inputs dynamically where 1 set = 3 dropdowns + 1 text input field and 1 remove button to remove that particular set. Now let's take set 1. If user selects something in first dropdown of this set it should change the options available in rest of the two drop downs in this same set. Please tell me if still i am unable to clearify myself.

Comment: edit post for clarification rather than comments . Much easier to see all in one place and get better response

Comment: sure, done the edit for question.

Comment: Also can you jest focus on your problem, split it out from other parts, current sample is hard to understand.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E3gWX/3/ check this out, i will explain if it does what you need

Comment: it is working kind of. I mean it is changing the options in the rest of two, but if i am making an selection in the third it is changing it in the first as well. Actually my first drop down is going to be "Type of Computer Device" where options may be "Laptop, Desktop, Router etc.". Then if Router is selected so in next that is "Brand of Device" where options should be according. Then in third it "Operating System" that is also having options in relevancy.

Comment: Do not re-ask the same question if you haven't got answer. You should edit your first question.

Comment: i wanted to delete that question as i was not getting any response bcz no one was able to understand it, also by the time i asked it again someone answered it and i was not able to delete it after that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code to change the next two selects to the value chose in the first one:

```
$('#dropbox').on('change', 'select', function() {
    if (! $(this).prev().length) { //if this is the first select
        val = $(this).val();//take value of first select
        $(this).next().val(val);       //and set it to the
        $(this).next().next().val(val);//two next selects
    }
})​;
```

See my working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/E3gWX/6/)

**UPDATE**:
So after OP comments, I'm adding here an example to replace the options for the next two selects, instead of just selecting from the existing ones, as my previous exampled did, here it is:

```
$('#dropbox').on('change', 'select', function() {
    if (! $(this).prev().length) { //if this is the first select
        //val = $(this).val();//take value of first select
        $(this).next().html($("<option>").val("0").text("NEW OPT 1").add( $("<option>").val("1").text("NEW OPT2")));
        $(this).next().next().html($("<option>").val("0").text("GOOD OPT 1").add( $("<option>").val("1").text("GOOD OPT2")));
    }
});
```

See it the live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/E3gWX/34/) .

Comment: Thank you for this. But, i have to change the whole set of options in the next drop drop and based on selection from second it should change the whole set of option in the last one that is third. I am not sure bcz i don't have any experience that how am i going to do this using your well working example. :(

Comment: @Harsh Ok, I've updated my answer with a new example where I replace the options of the two next select with new ones, use that code as template to replace the options for whichever you wanted, like from db,etc.  Let me know if this example is enough for you..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this demo does what you want if I understand correctly that you wish to change each select to same value on a row when one of them is changed

http://jsfiddle.net/E3gWX/1/

**EDIT:**

Your original concept was far too primitive for dependend chained selects. Here is a demo that will get you a lot closer to what you need
http://jsfiddle.net/Ywzjv/2/

Comment: actually it is generating but i want to be able to change the options as well for these dynamically generated dropdowns. Please read the question again as i just have edited it.

Comment: OK... you want dependent selects based on first... like "country/state/city". Where is data coming from?

Comment: you can rewrite `<select>` contents using html() function, or remove all it's data using `$(this).find('option').remove()` and then add with `add()`

Comment: Where is data coming from?? Even i am not having this answer. all i know is i got this working script from somewhere and i just want to change it to fit to my needs.

Comment: what is data for new options ? it should be something like hash: `var options={option1: ["suboption1","suboption2"],option2: ["suboption3","suboption4"]}`

Comment: updated with some arrays that you can use to try to build your options. Will need quite a bit more added to account for  user changes. You might be best off using a cascading select plugin that handles all this for you. Concept you want is far more complicated than your original code would hanlde

Comment: Thnx Charlie, it's working awesome. Can we remove the popup that comes after selecting (if it's not a problem for you!!)?

Comment: updated link above removed the alert popup...was using for debugging

Comment: i am now getting ERROR 404 :-(

Comment: 404 means link is incorrect and file doesn't exist. Not sure if you mean your server or fiddle.net

Comment: no i just clicked your above link http://jsfiddle.net/Ywzjv/1 and it's error 404. (was looking for the updated one)

Comment: revised link.. not sure what happened, I think was problem with me logged in to fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Ywzjv/2/

Comment: Got that new link and working perfectly fine in JSFIDDLE. Thnx. But, i am wondering if you can tell me that why is it not working in my html page. I put a link to jquery 1.8.2 and after that this script of yours in head tag and the html in body tag, but it is not doing anything. Actually i had this same problem with some other examples as well provided to me by someone else but no one helped me in this matter beyond providing the working JSFIDDLE. I know it's not someones problem to make it to work up to my html page but really i don't know how to get javascript to work if am stuck somewhere.

Comment: @charlietfl your fiddle is working perfectly in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer

Comment: works for me in IE 8 & 9. Will need some css to size selects, when they start empty and are filled on fly they aren't getting width but they work

Comment: But not working for me in my code can you help. This is the #dropbox div that it is getting append to `#dropbox {
 float:right;
}

#dropbox input {
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 width:150px;
}

#dropbox select {
 margin-left:10px;
 width:150px;
}
`. Also the problem is only with IE not google chrome, as well JSFIDDLE is also having the same problem. My dropbox div successfully increases the width but the text is still one character also it is not changing back if the select again a different option in first dropdown

Comment: it's the same as you gave to me. It's just not working completely well in IE

Comment: I can't help with what I can't replicate... works for me in several versions of IE. What version, what OS?

Comment: Alright i have asked one of my friends who have this domain for his customer to give it to me temporarily for some hours. it is www.reprar.com you can go over there and see the problem in action. I think this should help you to understand the problem in a better way. Also i have Windows 7 (64-bit) on two computers of mine and problem is same.

Comment: page needs validating, has a number of invalid tags  http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Freprar.com%2F. In order to do DOM manipulation your html has to be valid

Comment: Well what will you say about this then ?? [new link](http://reprar.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/E3gWX/33/) - it only does the the next one, not cascade, but you can use another .each(:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[id!=sel]").live('change',function(e) {
        selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val()
        if ($(this).next().attr('name').match(/input[0-9]_[0-9]/)) {
            $(this).next().find('option').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == selectedValue) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```