# Javascript: Replace backslashes with double backslashes

Tags: javascript, escaping, backslash

I'm currently having the problem mentioned in the title and I'm somehow not finding a way to properly replace backsashes with double backslashes, so that I can properly give the string to a webservice as parameters.
Let me show you what I tried. Some of these do actually work for some other people, but not for me... I'm currently testing this with FF18.0.1

```
WSParameters.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\\\\\");
WSParameters.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
WSParameters.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
WSParameters.replace(/\\/g, "&#92;&#92;");
WSParameters.replace(/\\/g, "&#92;");
WSParameters.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT: I should mention that it's somehow parsed into JSON and with firebug I see the backslash in the source string, but not in the JSON view. Maybe there is another way? But somehow it's already failing at the replacement of the backslashes.

EDIT2:

```
if (noAction == false) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/" + webMethod,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: pAsync,
        data: WSParameters,
        success: function callFunction(result) { processPOSTResults(result, pType, pNot);},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error while communicating with WebAdmin web service. - ' + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not this : WSParameters.replace('\', '\\ '

Comment: Because this will escape the ', so the string definition is broken.

Comment: Watch out with just relying on Firebug's output. When you log `"\\"` (a backslash) to the console, it prints as `"\"`. Similarly, `"\""` (a quote) is output as `"""`. By the looks of it, the third example should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Mattias, however I temporarily wrote my own replace method and fell into another problem. Now it seems that I can't provide the backslash in any way to th web service in JSON. \\\\, %5C, \u05C and &#92; don't seem to be acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WSParameters.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");` should do it, and in FF18 as well. Notice that if you use `JSON.stringify`, this is done automatically. Also watch out that many console outputs (Firebug etc) do surround string contents with quotes, but do not escape them.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I don't use JSON stringify, please se my EDIT 2 for the JSON WS part.

Comment: However maybe you *should* use it for [posting JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3854629/1048572)? What is `WSParameters`, how do you get it?

Comment: The WSParameters variable is a string and looks like this: {param1: 'abc', param2: 'def', list1: ['4711','4712']}

Comment: I'll have a look at this, thanks. But is this also possible with dynamically generated lists and nested lists?

Comment: How did you get that string? It's not valid JSON at all.

Comment: I built it based on the experience I made, this was the only format tht worked for me.

Comment: Your webservice only accepts javascript object literals, no [JSON](http://json.org)???

Comment: I guess it also accepts JSON, but I couldn't figure out the correct use and then went with the more convenient format. However it seems that this was the wrong decision.

Comment: Yes. Use an object, and `JSON.stringify` (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3854659/1048572)).

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that using the JSON format and  JSON.stringify solved the problem with the backslash in the web service parameters. Thanks again!